# Marketing Cloud export and import to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-loader, workbench

We're exporting a csv file from marketing cloud using a data extract activity. The delimiter is , 
The export contains salesforceID and another field. It's csv so the values are in one column but , separated.

We're having problems importing using dataloader and workbench developerforce. Data loader isn't activating the object and csv when the csv is selected.

Workbench developerforce gives an error that the final row contains 3 columns instead of 2.

Here's some example data:

```
contact_no_intg,person_salesforce_id,GDPR Status
12345678,000000000000000000,Opt in
12345679,000000000000000001,Opt in
12345670,000000000000000002,Opt in
```

I think it has something to do with the file type. Even though the file extension is .csv when I open the file it looks like it thinks it's a .txt, and when I save as a .csv I can upload.

I'd like to avoid having to open and save as. Is there a way to export the file from MC so I can upload to SF without changing anything? Or is there a way of automating the saving of the file type as?

Comment: Can you elaborate this [It's csv so the values are in one column but , separated.]? Also can you post some sample (redacted) records (header plus one or two lines)?

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue here but data loader requires UTF8 encoding. The standard export format of data extension extracts is UCS2 or something like that (don't remember exactly). You need to contact support to enable UTF8 encoding, which gives you a dropdown choice of encoding formats when you define a data extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Stephan, you're right. We had to ask Marketing Cloud support to enable an UTF16 to UTF8 data extract type.